# Post YouTube video into a Facebook Event Wall

Tags: javascript, facebook, facebook-graph-api, facebook-javascript-sdk

I try to post a YouTube video directly into a Facebook Event wall, using the Graph API.

When posting to a FanPage wall I get a desired result (Post with preview picture and the video itself), But when posting to an event wall, I only get the message, without any video and preview picture.

Here's the code:

```
var eventObj =
{
    source:'http://www.youtube.com/v/'+youTubeID,
    picture:'http://img.youtube.com/vi/'+youTubeID+'/0.jpg',
    message: messageText,
    name: eventName,
    caption: newDateArray[0] + ' ' + newDateArray[1].substr(0, 5)
}; 

FB.api('/'+facebookEventID+'/feed', 'post', eventObj, function(response){

//response code...

}
```

After this code is executed, I get a new post in the Event Wall, with only the `messageText` being displayed. I've tried sending only the `source`, but then it returns an error object with message it cant create a post without a message, so I tried sending both `source` and `message` and got the same result: only the message was displayed.

**UPDATE BASED ON ANSWER:**

I've tried using your code and your permissions, and the results are the same:

I get only the text:

[image]

Maybe its because I'm posting as a FanPage ?
Do you have any idea how to solve it ?

**UPDATE #2 BASED ON ANSWER:**

It seems that for some reason an event created from within Facebook has a newer version of the post UI then an event created from an application using the Graph API.

This is from the event created within Facebook:
[image]

And this is from the event created with the Graph API:
[image]

You can see the second is an older version, and I guess this difference is also causing the problem of uploading YouTube links to events created by the Graph API, As I succeed uploading a YouTube link from the API to an event created by me from within Facebook.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Really? I was able to post a YouTube link to an event using my test app:

```
function post() {
  var eid = 508688182476978;  // Event id.                                                                 
  FB.api(
    '/' + eid + '/feed',
    'post',
    {
      message: 'Testing SDK',
      source: 'http://www.youtube.com/v/kohozJp9dNs',
      picture: 'http://img.youtube.com/vi/kohozJp9dNs/0.jpg',
      caption: 'beach video (caption)'
    },
    function(response) {
      if (!response || response.error) {
        console.log(response);
        alert('Error occured');
      } else {
        alert('Post was successful! Action ID: ' + response.id);
      }
    }
  );
}
```

...and it shows the video's picture preview and caption:

[image: youtube link on an event]

...with these perms

```
publish_actions,read_stream,user_events,publish_stream
```

I did not need the `name` param like in your example.

### Events created via the API

If you are creating Events using the API (not creating them using a web browser), try enabling the 'Events Timezone' migration:

[App Dashboard](https://developers.facebook.com/apps) > Advanced > Migrations > Events Timezone > Enable

See also announcement of that migration: https://developers.facebook.com/blog/post/2012/08/01/platform-migration--events-timezone-support/

Once the Events Timezone migration is enabled for your app, create a new event using the api, and then try posting the YouTube video story as written above in `function post()`.

Comment: That's strange because I too am posting as a Page (not as a user).  My user is posting as a Page named "Dick Sharpewitz" (in my screenshot).  The user that is logged-in is an admin of the "Dick Sharpewitz" Page and creator of the event.  When you post on behalf of the user, is that user an admin of the Page or creator of the Event?  If not, try using an event that the user created.

Comment: The user is an admin of the Page, and the event was created by the page (from my website, by the Facebook API). Are your events created from Facebook or also from the API ?

Comment: I created the event in the screenshot using facebook.com (web browser)

Comment: Yep, This is definitively the problem, I'm able to upload YouTube videos to events I've created by my own, but not to events created by the application. I think its an issue in Facebook, as you can see (look at update #2 in my question), an event created from within Facebook has different post UI (and indeed a newer one) then an event created by the graph API call, so there are probably more differences between them... and maybe one of them is the YouTube parsing. Thanks a lot for the help ! your answer surely led me to investigate the issue more deeply.

Comment: Hey Alon_A, To get the "new" Events UI using the api, I would try enabling the 'Events Timezone' migration in your app settings in the [App Dashboard](https://developers.facebook.com/apps) > Advanced > Migrations > Events Timezone > Enable.  You did some good hunting.  See also announcement: https://developers.facebook.com/blog/post/2012/08/01/platform-migration--events-timezone-support

Comment: That indeed solved the problem, Thanks again ! ... But now I have a new problem.. Please look [On my new question](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/13100232/youtube-post-to-facebook-event-is-sent-and-displayed-on-the-event-page-but-doe), I've noticed the YouTube links on your Event Page are also not playable, just like my links. You have any idea about it ?