# YouTube post to Facebook Event is sent and displayed on the event page - but doesn't play

Tags: javascript, facebook, facebook-graph-api

Following [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13007621/post-youtube-video-into-a-facebook-event-wall), that was solved, I'm now able to send YouTube links to Facebook Events walls. But, when I try to play them, this error pops up:

[image]

You can see there is a difference in the look between YouTube posts that are being created directly in Facebook and YouTube post sent by the API (The upper post is the API and the lower one was created directly from the Facebook event Page).

[image]

I've checked the feeds by the Graph API Explorer and noticed that the working post from Facebook has a `"type": "video"` attribute, while the non playable post from the API has a `"type": "swf"` attribute.

My code is:

```
var eventObj =
{
    source:'http://www.youtube.com/v/'+youTubeID,
    picture:'http://img.youtube.com/vi/'+youTubeID+'/0.jpg',
    message: messageText,
    name: eventName,
    caption: newDateArray[0] + ' ' + newDateArray[1].substr(0, 5)
}; 

FB.api('/'+facebookEventID+'/feed', 'post', eventObj, function(response){

//response code...

}
```

When sending same values by the Graph API Explorer I got the same non playable post. I've tried modifying the sent properties, sending only the required source and picture attributes, but the result was the same non playable post.

Comment: This appears to be a bug. I can repro the behavior. Even setting `type: 'video'` doesn't help.  I would file a report using the [Bug Tool](https://developers.facebook.com/bugs/create)

Comment: I want to do it, but how can I give them the Steps to Reproduce ? They will need to be an admins of one of our pages and get an access token as my application (Trying to send a YouTube link with a Graph API Explorer Access Token didn't work for me, Only when selecting my application it sent the link from the API Explorer)  Do you have any idea ? Thanks... :)

Comment: Provide your appid and event id (or URL). And the URL to the story with the YouTube link. Also post the URL to the bug report here please